# for-loop with Double in Scala

Tags: scala, for-loop, double

its possible to use like bellow

```
val ls = for(i <- 1 to 5) yield i
```

but it's not possible to use this

```
val la:Double = 100000000000000d
val ls = for(i <- la to la + 1) yield i
```

because if the element is *Double*, **to** create *Range.Partial[Double,scala.collection.immutable.NumericRange[Double]]* which don't have *map*.

To use for-loop with *Double*, how to deal with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to specify the method `by` that will convert the range from `Range.Partial[Double,scala.collection.immutable.NumericRange[Double]]` into `scala.collection.immutable.NumericRange[Double]`

e.g.

```
for (i <- la to la + 1 by 1.0) yield i
```

**Update**

In the scala source code for `scala.collection.immutable.Range.Partial` class you can see their [reasoning](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.2/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Range.scala#L397-401) behind this.

There's no way of knowing what the default step size of your range is, unlike using an Integer range.